# WooCommerce Product Vendors - add editable roles

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I’m working with the WooCommerce Product Vendors plugin. I want to allow users with the role of Vendor Admin to add new users with the role of Vendor Manager. I already enabled the capability to list, create, etc. (`$role->add_cap( 'create_users')` and such). But, it turns out they can only create new Customers or Subscribers.

The restriction appears to be coming from inside a class in one of the plugin files - it’s very long so I’m just showing a bit of it here:

```
class WC_Product_Vendors_Vendor_Admin {

    public static $self;

    public static function init() {
        self::$self = new self();
        // filter the user roles
        add_filter( 'editable_roles', array( self::$self, 'filter_user_roles' ) );
    }

    public function filter_user_roles( $roles ) {
        $filtered_roles['customer'] = $roles['customer'];
        $filtered_roles['subscriber'] = $roles['subscriber'];
        return $filtered_roles;
    }
}
```

If I add in `$filtered_roles['wc_product_vendors_manager_vendor'] = $roles['wc_product_vendors_manager_vendor'];` then Vendor Manager shows up in the role dropdown for Add Users, and it works.

But instead of modifying the plugin directly, I want to do it in my custom plugin. At first I thought to add a filter to the "filter_user_roles" function, but I don't know how to target it since it's in a class. Is this possible? I also tried various ways of making my own filter for 'editable_roles', but I haven't been able to get it right. (The only examples I've found with it are of how to remove roles, not add them back when something else is removing them).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out with help from [here](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/editable_roles-adding-roles/#post-14955761) and [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/214281/new-users-are-saved-with-no-role-selected).

I had to include the capabilities for the roles, even though they're already defined in the plugin. I made a function to return the capabilities from it, and then used it in my add_editable_roles function. This is what worked:

```
function get_role_caps_1() {
    class WC_Product_Vendors_Roles_Caps_2 extends WC_Product_Vendors_Roles_Caps {
      public function default_manager_vendor_caps(){
        return parent::default_manager_vendor_caps();
      }
    }
    $Class_Inst = new WC_Product_Vendors_Roles_Caps_2();
    return $Class_Inst->default_manager_vendor_caps();
}

function add_editable_roles ( $roles ) {
    if ( current_user_has_role('wc_product_vendors_admin_vendor')) {        
        $filtered_roles = array(
        'wc_product_vendors_manager_vendor' => array(
            "name" => "Vendor Manager",
            "capabilities" => get_role_caps_1(),
            ),
        );
        return $filtered_roles; 
    } else {
        return $roles;
    }
}

add_filter( 'editable_roles', 'add_editable_roles', 12);
```